# Nginx: When the `index` and `try_files` in the same block, why the `try_files` will be processed, not the `index` directive?

Tags: nginx

The nginx.conf is as following:

```
http {
    server {
        listen  8080;
        server_name example.com;             
        root /tmp/test/example;
        location / {
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri /test.html;
        }

    }
}
```

When I access `example.com:8080`, it accesses the `/tmp/test/example/test.html`, not the `index.html`.

Comment: How about `try_files $uri $uri/ /test.html;`?

Comment: @RichardSmith, it accessed the file `index.html`, why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `try_files` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

It specifically documents two *file* elements: `$uri` and `$uri/`. The first tests for the presence of normal files and the second for the presence of directories.

The `index` directive is invoked as a consequence of processing a URI which points to a directory which contains a file matching one of the directives parameters.

In the case of `try_files $uri /test.html;`, the existence of a directory is not tested, and therefore the default action is taken.

In the case of `try_files $uri $uri/ /test.html;`, the existence of a directory *is* tested, and therefore the index action is taken.

Comment: Testing for the existence of a directory, does the directory refers to the `root direcory`?@Richard Smith

Comment: @zhenguoli In the case of the URI `/`, the answer is yes.

Comment: The directory refers to the directory which you request in the URI, right?@Richard Smith